# Proxy Issue while checking accessibility of URLs from client machine

Tags: java, spring-boot, proxy

I am working on an application where I have to write a logic in java (Spring Boot) to check whether some URLs like ‘www.google.ca’ and ‘https://10.23.333.43:8988/abc’ (Internal url of company) etc. can be accessed from various Windows machines. Java (Spring Boot)  Code needs to be hosted on a RHEL Unix box. Means RHEL Unix box which host the code is server and some Windows machines are clients machines on which URLs accessibility needs to be tested. Unix box as well as Windows machines all of them are behind proxy to connect to internet. I know the proxy value on Unix box but do not know the proxy details on Windows machines.

First I tried below code where I tried to fetch proxy first and then set the proxy to System properties and then execute the code to check accessibility of URLs from client machines.

// Fetch proxy details and set system proxy before executing the code to check accessibility of URLs from client machines

```
  System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

  List<Proxy> l = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("https://www.google.ca/"));             

  for (Iterator<Proxy> iter = l.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {

     Proxy proxy = iter.next();

     logger.debug("proxy type : " + proxy.type());

     InetSocketAddress addr = (InetSocketAddress) proxy.address();                 

     if (addr == null) {

        logger.debug("No Proxy");

     } else {

        logger.debug("proxy hostname : " + addr.getHostName());

        proxyMap.put(Constants.PROXY_KEY, addr.getHostName());

        logger.debug("proxy port : " + addr.getPort());

        proxyMap.put(Constants.PORT_KEY, addr.getPort()+"");

     }

  }
```

// Code to check accessibility of URLs from client machines

```
URL  url = new URL(tempUrl);                                   

HttpURLConnection  http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

Integer statusCode = http.getResponseCode();
```

but I face some issues with above code when I deploy the code on unix box and then test it from Test Windows machine.

Issue 1: I see that above code will tell me the accessibility of required URLs on Unix box only as it does not involve any input from client machines like IP.

Issue 2: I am not able to fetch proxy details of client machines (It says proxy type is DIRECT). However same code for proxy fetching works on my windows development machine where client and server is same machine.

Then I checked some other solution on internet where I tried to check accessibility of URLs using IP address of client machine. I tried below code (with proxy code remains same).

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.google.ca/");

httpget.setConfig(requestConfig);

logger.debug("executing request-> " + httpget.getRequestLine());
```

I faced below issues with above code.

Issue 1: I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when processing request to /10.61.241.79->{s}->https://www.google.ca:443: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)

Issue 2: I am not able to fetch proxy details of client machines (It says proxy type is DIRECT). However same code for proxy fetching works on my windows development machine where client and server is same machine.

Please help me how can I check accessibility to the URLs from client Windows machine.

Edit 1: I fixed my issue by moving the code to UI (HTML) layer and wrote down the logic in javascript which runs on client browser. By that way, I am able to hit the URLs for accessibility. My suggestion is to run the accessibility code always on client end rather than service layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to check reach-ability of URLs, then you should try using XMLHttpRequest object and then use GET method of Ajax in Jquery. That way you may not need proxy as code will run on client end.